# imageview is not changing correctly when spinner item is clicked

Tags: android

I have three images "item1, item2, item3" and I want to show the "item1.png" when the "Select items" option of the spinner is clicked and also at first (as default), "item2.png" when the item2 of the spinner is clicked and so on.

The issue is that is always appearing the image "item2.png" at first (as default), but at first I would like to show the "item1.png" that because it is the "Select items" item that is selected at first and I want to associate the "item1.png" to the "Select items" item.

Do you know why is the "item2.png" that is showing at first? Also if I click in the "Select items" the "item1.png" dont shows, it shows also the "item2.png". But when I click in the "item3" it shows corretly the "item3.png" image.

strings xml:

```
<string-array name="spinner_values">
<item>Select items</item>
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
</string-array>
```

code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            String string = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());


            final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);



            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
                        case 1:
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item3);
                            break;
                        default:
                            //Default image
                            //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                            break;

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.ricardorei.tpc.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="321dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="Are Awesome!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.517"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="134dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:entries="@array/spinner_values"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You miss a `break;` in your switch statement on the end of `case 0:`
2. Set your default selection with `spinner.setSelection(0);`

Answer (score 0):

you haven't created a adapter for spinner.

Spinner needs a adapter to work.

Add adapter then check